# Non UV unwrap (geometrical/rotary unwrap) for CNC - is it possible?

Tags: uv

Is it possible to make such type of unwrapping inside Blender or with script or addon?

This procedure is used in CAD/CAM software to transform a model for rotary processing on CNC, when Y axis is substituted by rotary axis.
[image]

[image]